# Giving limited Sudo privilege to a user

Tags: 14.04, sudo, steam

I've heard it can be done but have found no documentation on it. Specifically I want to give someone the ability to use their password as sudo for a steam application.

Comment: Why do you need to run steam as root?

Comment: EDIT yes I know really old games require root permission. Sadly it may be best to avoid these...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [command aliases](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Command_Aliases) to limit what commands the user can run as `sudo` - e.g. this `/etc/sudoers` restricts the user to commands needed to do admin:

```
# define host aliases
Host_Alias HOSTNAME = laptop

# define command aliases
Cmnd_Alias ARCH = /bin/tar, /bin/gzip, /bin/gunzip
Cmnd_Alias CRYPT = /sbin/losetup, /sbin/cryptsetup
Cmnd_Alias DIR = /bin/mkdir, /bin/rmdir
Cmnd_Alias DEVICE = /sbin/ifup, /sbin/ifdown
Cmnd_Alias DISK = /bin/mount, /bin/umount
Cmnd_Alias EDIT = /usr/bin/nano, /usr/bin/gedit
Cmnd_Alias FILE = /bin/cp, /bin/echo, /bin/ln, /bin/mv, /bin/rm, /usr/bin/touch, /usr/bin/rename
Cmnd_Alias FORMAT = /sbin/mkfs.ext2, /sbin/mkfs.ext3, /sbin/mkfs.ext4, /sbin/mkfs.msdos, /sbin/mkfs.vfat
Cmnd_Alias NAV = /usr/bin/nautilus
Cmnd_Alias NETWORK = /sbin/route, /sbin/iptables, /usr/bin/nmap, /usr/sbin/hping3
Cmnd_Alias PERM = /bin/chattr, /bin/chgrp, /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
Cmnd_Alias PROCESS =  /usr/bin/ps, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/killall, /sbin/shutdown
Cmnd_Alias SELINUX = /usr/sbin/semanage, /usr/bin/chcon, /sbin/restorecon, /usr/sbin/setsebool
Cmnd_Alias SERVERS = /etc/init.d/network, /etc/init.d/cups, /etc/init.d/nfs, /etc/init.d/httpd, /etc/init.d/vsftpd
Cmnd_Alias SERVICE = /usr/bin/systemctl, /sbin/chkconfig, /sbin/service, /usr/sbin/updatedb
Cmnd_Alias SOFTWARE = /usr/bin/dpkg, /usr/bin/apt-get
Cmnd_Alias VIEW = /bin/cat, /usr/bin/du, /bin/ls, /bin/tree, /bin/top, /bin/tails

# define access
root ALL = (ALL) ALL
wilf HOSTNAME = NOPASSWD: ARCH, CRYPT, DIR, DISK, DEVICE, EDIT, FILE, FORMAT, NAV, NETWORK, PERM, PROCESS, SERVERS, SERVICE, SOFTWARE, VIEW
```

<sup>*Don't just copy and paste this. Read the manual (`man sudoers`) and try and understand what it does first to keep your system secure. Particularly the `NOPASSWD` bits (the above is intended for device that doesn't need that great security). Also check afterwards whether users can't `sudo -i` around it etc.*</sup>

You can also assign commands to specific groups instead of individual users. For example, to allow users in the group `wheel` (this needs to exist and have the needed users added to it) to shutdown the computer with `sudo shutdown`... and no password:

```
 %wheel ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

With the specifics of getting a steam application (or a certain program) to run, find/create a launcher for it (usually in `~/.local/share/applications` if done by a local user), you can use that to find the command you need to run it - please note this usually refers to a program stored in `~/.local/share`. HOWEVER, usually giving a user sudo access to a script in a editable directory is a REALLY BAD IDEA as they could swap out the script with their own one to get elevated access. If you do want to give them access to a few scripts, make sure they are only editable by `root` (e.g. in `/sbin` with the correct permission). If you don't trust a user, don't give them sudo access.

Comment: I've create `custom` file on `/etc/sudoers.d/` folder and comment(`%sudo` and `%smith`) on `sudoers` file for `smith` user but still `sudo` is working, can you say that why ?

Comment: Based on your question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906868/how-to-prevent-to-change-etc-directory-by-sudo-user) that may not be the easiest/best solution - what did you put after the `%smith` etc lines? If you do ask a new question *please specify what they need to be able to access*, and show the `sudoers` etc methods you have tried. BTW it may be best to give the users only sudo access to some custom scripts (WITH LIMITED USER INPUT).