# How to prevent to change /etc directory by sudo user

Tags: permissions, sudo

We have an Ubuntu 14.04 machine in our lab and my plan is to restrict changing anything in the `/etc` directory by users with `sudo` privilege so that only the root user can edit the configuration files.

Is there any software to apply this type of policy like there is in Windows server?

Comment: why would you give a `sudo` privilege to users you can't trust editing configuration files?

Comment: I give to all privilege except /etc directory.

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: User are change the resolve.conf, apache conf etc. files, result may going wrong.

Comment: why do you want to give those users `sudo` privilege?

Comment: Anyone with sudo privileges can change to root in terminal (`sudo -i` or `sudo su root`). Hence, anyone with sudo privileges will still have access to /etc. The exercise seems pointless.

Comment: Ok, Here my plan is to user can kill the process, restart all services, mount, change permission and owner, ifdown/up, vagrant etc.

Comment: See the link in the answer. What you want can be done that way but you need to make a command for anything you want them to be able to do.

Comment: Of course, if you give a user mount permissions, they can just mount a small filesystem over `/etc`.  If you're going to roll your own security model, it becomes your responsibility to make it consistent and coherent, and that's not easy.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to create a user group that has the privileges to run and manage *specific* services, manage *specific* network interfaces and mount to mountpoints that are *white-listed* or *that they own*. Unrestricted mount privileges can be escalated trivially to generic super-user privileges as can unrestricted ownership and access permission changes. You'll want to think about the latter a little more.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no software for that. And if there was a "sudo" user would be able to revert what that software changed for a user not being able to change anything in  `/etc`.

If you do not trust your users do not make them a "sudo" user and create regular users for them.

> Ok, Here my plan is to user can kill the process, restart all services, mount, change permission and owner, ifdown/up, vagrant etc.

But that has nothing to do with being able to not change `/etc`: you can have a regular user with elevated power so (s)he can use specific commands that require "sudo" without being admin on that machine. Example of this:  [Giving limited Sudo privilege to a user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654832/giving-limited-sudo-privilege-to-a-user) Setting it up like this means they can not change anything in `/etc` unless you create a command where they can. But if you believe it is a good idea to have a user be able to do anything except changing files in `/etc` it is going to be a very long list.

Be careful though: it is easy to add conflicting commands. See the comment from [msalters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906868/how-to-prevent-to-change-etc-directory-by-sudo-user#comment1424552_906868) for instance.

Comment: For example, if you have "change permission and owner" then you have the ability to run anything as root (and thus do anything you want).

Comment: Never mind being able to edit a specific configuration file. Most editors (particularly those that are designed to run in a terminal) have facilities to shell out, either to a shell or to execute an arbitrary command from within the editor, so by allowing a user to edit a specific file, you may be enabling them to execute arbitrary shell commands as the user that owns that file.

Answer (score 0):

or you could try to chattr +Rais /etc
it will however deny any changes to /etc folder by anyone too, and must instruct whoever updates / configures stuff on the system to chattr -Rais the folder before doing so.
However this is not really a solution, one can revert the changes if he knows, how.
If you don't trust the users, i would advice installing "rootsh" - it's an app that logs EVERYTHING a user does, including his output.

Comment: *"i would advice installing "rootsh" - it's an app that logs EVERYTHING a user does, including his output"* and that will take someone with root access how long exactly to bypass? Counting down... three... two... one...